# Why I can't touch the button in alert view, right after I see the alert?

Tags: ios, testing, cucumber, bdd, frank

I'm testing iOS application by using the automation framework named "Frank"

And there were some alert popped up in my application I need to cover.

I've wrote my feature file as below:

```
Scenario:
    I input wrong username and password, I should see the log failed alert.
...

    When I wait to see "Log failed"
    Then I touch the button marked "OK"
```

Unfortunately, this code won't work, although frank(cucumber) will mark the test step of touch "OK" button as Pass, but actually, the button won't be touched.

I have to do it like this:

```
Scenario:
    I input wrong username and password, I should see the log failed alert.
...

    When I wait to see "Log failed"
    #Wait for 1 sec in order to touch the button.
    And I wait for 1 second

    Then I touch the button marked "OK"
```

Comment: I'm not an expert of the framework you're using, but it could be that the touch happens while the animation of the UIAlertView is still running and at that time the button is not yet touchable.

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli I agree with you, this is my best guess. And if you want, you can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment above is probably correct - as for a different (better?) solution - depending on how comfortable you are with ruby, you could write your own step definition?  Frank provides you the

```
Frank::Cucumber::WaitHelper.wait_until
```

method, which you could wrap around your touch the button code, to give you a longer implicit wait on the element. See here for some documentation: https://github.com/moredip/Frank/blob/master/gem/lib/frank-cucumber/wait_helper.rb